# using $uibmodal to open from another controller and template

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm somehow newbie to $uibmodal and I want to show a form in popup style for each button that I have on my page, and I want to separate code of each popup form to their own js controller and template, not inside my main js controller and template.

here's my simpled code to show the form as a popup :

```js
 var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                    templateUrl: '/App/views/security/people/roleView.html',
                    controllerUrl: '/App/views/security/people/roleController.js',
                    controller: 'roleController',
                    size: 'lg',
                    resolve: {},
                });
```

and here is my simpled code of my controller :

```js
define(['app'], function (app) {
    app.register.controller("roleController", ["$scope", "dataService", "$uibModal", "messageService",

    function ($scope, dataService, $uibModal, messageService) {

    debugger
}
]);
});
```

my problem is that whenever I click the button it give's me the error that my controller named as 'rolecontroller' is not registered.

**The controller with the name 'roleController' is not registered.**

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to register the controller in the initial bootstrap, app.controller();

Comment: @MarcusHöglund you mean in app.js? how can I do that in there?

Comment: Yes, add app.controller("roleController", ["$scope", "dataService", "$uibModal", "messageService", function(...

Comment: @MarcusHöglund  thank you very much. it seems works :). Post your comment as an answer.

Comment: Np, great that it solved it. added the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You should add the controller in the initial bootstrap in your app.js like this

```
app.controller("roleController", ["$scope", "dataService", "$uibModal", "messageService",

    function ($scope, dataService, $uibModal, messageService) {

    debugger
}]);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but my problem hasn't been resolved completely, now I must copy my whole controller into app.js, but I want to have a separate file for my controller.

Comment: @eFarzad You can still have a seperat file. Make sure its loaded initially just

Comment: it just goes to app.js and doesn't go after "rolecontroller.js" at all.

Comment: @eFarzad have you checked that the rolecontroller.js is refered when you run/build the app?

Comment: now when I click on the button it is now popup the form that I want, but it seems it doesn't find the rolecontroller and my buttons on the popup form do not work.